# How to automatically start an image slider when the document loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to JavaScript & jQuery. I'm trying out some code for an image slider which works fine on an image click event. However, I want it to run all by itself after the document loads. How can I achieve this? I tried to place the code inside `$(document).ready()` but it doesn't work that way. Here's my code:

```
<script>
var total = 4;
var present = 1;
var next = 2;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#right").click(function () {
        present_slide = "#slide" + present;
        next_slide = "#slide" + next;
        $(present_slide).css("top", "200px");
        $(next_slide).css("top", "0px");
        present++;
        next++;
        if (present == (total + 1)) {
            present = 1;
            next = 2;
            for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                $("#slide" + i).css("top", "200px");
            }
            $("#slide1").css("top", "0px");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here - `#right` is the id associated with an img element. `#slide1`, `#slide2`, etc are the ids associated with the divs that hold multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$( "#right" ).trigger( "click" );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `$(document).ready()` by `$(window).onload = function(){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the `$("#right").click(function () {` or add `$('#right').trigger('click')`.

```
var total = 4;
var present = 1;
var next = 2;
$(document).ready(function () {
    present_slide = "#slide" + present;
    next_slide = "#slide" + next;
    $(present_slide).css("top", "200px");
    $(next_slide).css("top", "0px");
    present++;
    next++;
    if (present == (total + 1)) {
        present = 1;
        next = 2;
        for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            $("#slide" + i).css("top", "200px");
        }
        $("#slide1").css("top", "0px");
    }
});
```

Or

```
var total = 4;
var present = 1;
var next = 2;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#right").click(function () {
        present_slide = "#slide" + present;
        next_slide = "#slide" + next;
        $(present_slide).css("top", "200px");
        $(next_slide).css("top", "0px");
        present++;
        next++;
        if (present == (total + 1)) {
            present = 1;
            next = 2;
            for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                $("#slide" + i).css("top", "200px");
            }
            $("#slide1").css("top", "0px");
        }
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger the `click' event for the image when the window loads by

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#right").trigger('click');
}
```

This would trigger the click once all the resources are loaded.

Comment: You made the same typo that I did...  `trigger`

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of your script block, place this line:

```
$("#right").trigger('click');
```